# Homebrew node installation fails on cannot link c-ares

Tags: macos, homebrew

If I run `brew install node` I get this error:

> ==> Installing dependencies for node: c-ares, icu4c, libnghttp2, libuv and openssl@1.1
> Error: Cannot link c-ares
> Another version is already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/c-ares/1.17.1

Anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, it appears Homebrew tried to upgrade `c-ares` from version 1.17.1 to 1.18.1 but failed for some reason. Try running `brew upgrade c-ares` before `brew install node`.

If that doesn't work, what is your output for `brew list --versions c-ares`? Perhaps you have multiple `c-ares` versions installed. If that is the case, run `brew unlink c-ares` to unlink the old version and then `brew link c-ares` to link the newer one. The old version can be uninstalled by running `brew cleanup c-ares`

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, try

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* \
&& sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

This works if that error appears when installing anything on brew.
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45009

Answer (score 0):

Related to Elias / avariant's answer:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

(wait for code to execute)

`brew unlink c-ares`

worked for me